# Audio Sound Playing onload when its supposed to be a timed event

Tags: javascript

The audio is set to play at certain times, like an alarm clock built into the background of my home page. It's playing at the correct times. However, it's also playing on the loading of the web page for some reason. If anyone can figure it out that'd be very much appreciated as I am clueless.

```
var date = new Date(),
    year = date.getFullYear(),
    month = date.getMonth(),
    weekday = date.getDay(),
    day = date.getDate(),
    time = date.getTime(),
    timeout1 = new Date(year, month, day, 12, 15, 0, 0).getTime() - time,
    timeout2 = new Date(year, month, day, 14, 30, 0, 0).getTime() - time,
    timeout3 = new Date(year, month, day, 17, 0, 0, 0).getTime() - time,
    timeout4 = new Date(year, month, day, 19, 0, 0, 0).getTime() - time,
    timeout5 = new Date(year, month, day, 23, 45, 0, 0).getTime() - time,
    mp3 = new Audio("audio/alarm.mp3"),
    ogg = new Audio("audio/alarm.ogg"),
    audio;

if (typeof mp3.canPlayType === "function" && mp3.canPlayType("audio/mpeg") !== "")
    audio = mp3;
else if (typeof ogg.canPlayType === "function" && ogg.canPlayType("audio/ogg") !== "")
    audio = ogg;

setTimeout(function(){
    if (weekday > 0 && weekday < 6) {
        audio.play();
    }
}, timeout1);
setTimeout(function(){
    if (weekday > 0 && weekday < 6) {
        audio.play();
    }
}, timeout2);
setTimeout(function(){
    if (weekday > 0 && weekday < 6) {
        audio.play();
    }
}, timeout3);
setTimeout(function(){
    if (weekday > 0 && weekday < 6) {
        audio.play();
    }
}, timeout4);
setTimeout(function(){
    if (weekday > 0 && weekday < 6) {
        audio.play();
    }
}, timeout5);
```

Comment: add a `console.log()` in each of your timeouts to see which one is playing

Comment: Definitely the first one so jasonmmiraglia is correct so far, just figuring out how to make it a positive time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

timeout1 is a negative value because it is after 12 noon. At least in my timezone EST. So you should probably add a condition for positive times.

You can just wrap your timeouts in an if clause like:

```
if(timout1 > 0){
setTimeout(function(){
    if (weekday > 0 && weekday < 6) {
        audio.play();
    }
}, timeout1);
}
```

Also, I would restructure this to limit you from rewriting everything for each timeout.

```
var date = new Date(),
    year = date.getFullYear(),
    month = date.getMonth(),
    weekday = date.getDay(),
    day = date.getDate(),
    time = date.getTime(),
    timeouts = [],
    timeouts.push(new Date(year, month, day, 12, 15, 0, 0).getTime() - time),
    timeouts.push(new Date(year, month, day, 14, 30, 0, 0).getTime() - time),
    timeouts.push(new Date(year, month, day, 17, 0, 0, 0).getTime() - time),
    timeouts.push(new Date(year, month, day, 19, 0, 0, 0).getTime() - time),
    timeouts.push(new Date(year, month, day, 23, 45, 0, 0).getTime() - time),
    mp3 = new Audio("audio/alarm.mp3"),
    ogg = new Audio("audio/alarm.ogg"),
    audio;

if (typeof mp3.canPlayType === "function" && mp3.canPlayType("audio/mpeg") !== "")
    audio = mp3;
else if (typeof ogg.canPlayType === "function" && ogg.canPlayType("audio/ogg") !== "")
    audio = ogg;

for(var i=0;i<timeouts.length;i++){
    if(timeouts[i] > 0){
        setTimeout(function(){
            audio.play();
        }, timeouts[i]);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Corrected error due to typos.